# Rewritecond Query String search on subpages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

I'm writing to you because of an obstacle i found with .htaccess and Query String. What I need now to achieve is search inside subpages from FORM by GET method. I tried everything found on the internet on yesterday's evening. What partly works is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^checkin=(.*)&checkout=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/%2/%3/? [L,R=301]
```

This script gives a result from:

```
/chocolate/?checkin=15-08-2016&checkout=18-08-2016
```

to:

```
/15-08-2016/18-08-2016/
```

Probably it's very easy for you to make this subpage be the first before checkin & checkout. I wasted many hours but couldn't make it work properly. I mean:

```
/chocolate/15-08-2016/18-08-2016/
```

I even tried to send this subpage's name through INPUT type HIDDEN but it also wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning `chocolate` anywhere:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^checkin=([^\s&]+)&checkout=([^\s&]+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /chocolate/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]
```